# Access databound combo box c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, selectedvalue

I have an issue with a combo box control. Items are retrieved from the database, but it won't let me access it via **SelectedValue** property.

I tried setting it up like this:

```
DataSet ds = retrieveData(); //I am calling a procedure, it works fine
myComboBox.DataSource = ds;
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "COLUMN1";
myComboBox.ValueMember= "COLUMN2";
```

But it wouldn't work. The text in the combo box was

> System.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor

So I did this:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        myComboBox.Items.Add(
        new { TEXT = dr["COLUMN1"].ToString(), 
              VALUE = Convert.ToInt32(dr["COLUMN2"].ToString()) 
        });
    }
```

Now it works. But I have to access the index (`myComboBox.IndexOf("Text inside")`) instead of the value (which is primary key, therefore guaranteed to be unique). SelectedValue is always null, and the SelectedIndex is an anonymous object which fields I can't access either!

Any help?

Comment: It would be intersting to know why the first examples doesn't work. The second one cannot use SelectedValue because there is no DataSource binded. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379183/combobox-selectedvalue-throws-null-reference-exception

Comment: @Steve because then the text in the box is: `System.Data.DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind your ComboBox to a `DataTable` Object rather than a `DataSet`.
object. That will solve your purpose. Also, ensure that `DropDownStyle` property is Set to `DropDownList`. (This way user is forced to select a value from the list rather than typing.)

```
myComboBox.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```